# SQL Update incrementation is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, increment

I have small problem with my SQL code:

```
UPDATE articles SET like=like+1 WHERE id=1
```

When I'm trying to execute it in PhpMyAdmin, I'm getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like=like+1 WHERE id=1' at line 1
```

Column like is int defaultly set to 0 (length 11).
Does anybody know how can I repair it? Please help.

Comment: I think that's because `like` is a reserved word.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LIKE is a keyword and cannot be used as a column name. You could change it (in your query) to `` `like`=`like`+1 `` (with backticks), but that's hardly solving the problem.

Rename your column.

Answer (score 4):

Quote your field names:

```
UPDATE `articles` SET `like` = `like`+1 WHERE `id` = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

you set the field "like" the same with keyword LIKE of Sql so the error is appeared. Just change the name of field.